# Error while installing steam

Tags: steam

You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libc.so.6 this is the error i keep getting when trying to install steam on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Do in terminal:

> sudo apt-get install libc6

If wouldn't help try this:

> sudo apt-get install '^libc6.*'